# Change type of variable to point to a different struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have a struct that change a field's type based on a version (variable):

```c
typedef struct __base {
    char count[10];
    void *entry[10];
} Base;

typedef struct __base_16 {
    u_int16 count[10];
    void *entry[10];
} Base16;

void main() {
   /* version is computed at runtime based on some parameters */
   if (version >= 2) {
       Base *b = malloc(sizeof(Base));
   } else {
       Base16 *b = malloc(sizeof(Base16));
   }

   b->count[0] = 10;
   b->count[1] = 20;
}
```

Of course this code doesn't compile, what are clean alternative to be able to access the struct without using a void pointer and casting every access to the fields?

Comment: One good way would be to never access the fields outside of a very small and carefully guarded section of the program. To enforce this, *define* the struct in a single .c file, and only *declare* it in a header. The rest of the program will have no direct access to the fields. By the way, having an identifier that starts with `__` in your program is undefined behaviour.

Comment: Can the version be made a #define read from a header file?  This is an idiomatic way used eg. for compilers to select variations in how objects are defined.  Then the struct would be built only one way based on `#ifdef` sections in its definition.  Also allowing a more generic name for your typedef, from which it follows your code would only have to reference one name for all instances of the struct.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Can you elaborate more the method you suggest? What should I put in the header file and what in the c file? I should have two different implementation of a struct but access them the same way

Comment: @ryyker the version is computed at runtime, but  refactoring the code should made possible the use of the #ifdef.

Comment: you put definitions of both structs in the C file, and also all the functions that access the fields. The functions should only accept a pointer of *one* type, and cast it according to the version variable. The parameter could be a pointer to a union containing both structs, or just an opaque pointer (you put `struct OpaqueBase;` in the header file, with no fields).

Answer (score 1):

Per my comment:  If the version value can set using a #define read from a header file it might be an idiomatic way to do this, eg. #defines are commonly used to define variations in how objects are defined for large code base project. Using this method, the struct would be built only one way based on `#ifdef` sections that determine how the struct will be defined. This approach allows for a more generic name for your `typedef`, from which it follows your code would only have to reference one name for all instances of the struct

```
//in environment setting or header file
#define BASE_16 

//in source .c, or in .h
#ifdef BASE_16
typedef struct {
    u_int16 count[10];
    void *entry[10];
} count_t;//common name for all definitions, allowing for
          //simpler references in code that uses it
#endif

#ifdef BASE_8
typedef struct {
    u_int8 count[10];
    void *entry[10];
} count_t;
#endif

#ifdef BASE_32
typedef struct {
    u_int32 count[10];
    void *entry[10];
} count_t;
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, you would like to execute code, which looks the same for variables which have significantly distinct types, and write this code only once while the variable type is recognized at runtime?
I do not think, it is possible in C. Processor must execute significantly different instructions, so it must be reflected in the C code. I would propose to put all that identical code in a function, which gets your ‘changing-type-variable’ as an argument. Then copy this function in editor, and just change its name and argument type. Like this:

```
void func(Base *b)
{
   b->count[0] = 10;
   b->count[1] = 20;
...
}
void func16(Base16 *b)
{
   b->count[0] = 10;
   b->count[1] = 20;
...
}
void main() {
   /* version is computed at runtime based on some parameters */
   if (version >= 2) {
       Base *b = malloc(sizeof(Base));
       func(b); 
   } else {
       Base16 *b16 = malloc(sizeof(Base16));
       func16(b16); 
   }
}
```

Let me do a remark: In somehow opposite case, when coding for different types must be applied to the same space in memory, union works very well, like e.g.:

```
union count
{
    char CNTC[10];
    u_int16 CNT16[10];
} Count;
```